# include [[snippet]];

Tags: modx

I have two snippets in ModX:
first (DBData):

```
    <?php
// login.php
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_database = 'my_db';
$db_username = 'myusername';
$db_password = 'mypass';
```

second:

```
    <?php
require_once '[[DBData]]';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_database)
    or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());
```

When I try to insert them into my page like this:
[[DBData]]
[[DBConnect]]
Nothing happens, how can I "insert" DBData to DBConnect?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [modx API runSnippet](http://wiki.modxcms.com/index.php/API%3arunSnippet) to run a snippet within another snippet.

Further looking into your question it looks like you want to use the login details set in the 1st snippet in the 2nd. You could do this by setting placeholders in the first snippet and then using them in your 2nd as follows in your first snippet

```
$modx->setPlaceholder('host-name', 'localhost')
```

and then retrieve the value in your 2nd snippet

```
$modx->getPlaceholder('host-name')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend using the datbase MODx already has, you can use a syntax similar to this i you don't want to go into teh xPDO bussiness:

```
<?php
$rows = array();
$result = $modx->query("SELECT * FROM `xyz`");
if ($result) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($rows, $row);
    }
}
```

If you really want to use your own connection, than perhaps it is better to store your own system setting with the database credentials (maybe withou password) in the MODx configtuation and than get them in the snippet by:

```
$mySetting = $modx->getOption('your_setting_key');
```

For creating your own system sesttings enries, see http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/settings/system-settings/